# Best Practice to Draw Path Offset to One Side with Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cgcontext, cgpath

It is possible to offset a CGPath using:

```
CGPath.copy(strokingWithWidth:lineCap:lineJoin:miterLimit:transform‌​:)
```

[image]

This creates a path offset of the center of the original (black) path, shown as gray in the left example of above image.

I need to be able to offset the path on one side or the other (inside or outside) of the original path (gray area from the example on the right).

Will I need to create a new path (shown in orange dashed line), connect it to the original path and then fill, or is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: You need do this by any means or only copying your path?

Comment: I would be open to the possibility of any means.

Comment: OK, I will work in some answer and i will post my results as soon as i can